# Проверка строки на содержание только цифр

Tags: php

**$var** может содержать текст, текст с цифрами и только цифры.

Как поймать тот момент, когда переменная содержи только цифры и выполнить условия

```
if (...) {
   //содержит только цифры
}
```

Comment: а цифры могут быть через пробел быть или как? какие варианты когда только цифры? Примеры напишите

Answer (score 0):

1. Если не использовать регулярные выражения.

В зависимости от того, что будет в переменной $var. Или string, или integer.

a)

```
if (is_numeric($var))
```

Подробнее [is_numeric в php](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php)

b)

```
if (ctype_digit($var))
```

Подробнее [ctype_digit в php](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ctype-digit.php)

Во второй ссылке пример #2 разницу в этих функциях показывает.

2. Регулярным выражением

   if (preg_match('/[^\d]/', $var))